# Checking object inside callback after dealloc

Tags: ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

Bear with me as I try to explain this.

I have an instance of HJManagedImageV inside a UITableViewCell.
I set it's callback to self, a UIVIewController implementing the
needed protocol (HJManagedImageVDelegate).

When I navigate to then quickly away from this controller, callbacks are
eventually fired on objects that are no longer around. (HJManagedImageV
retains its delegates.)

The problem is that inside the callback I cannot check
if the object is valid without getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
-(void)managedImageSet:(HJManagedImageV*)mi {

    mi.callbackOnSetImage = nil;

    if(mi != nil && mi.image != nil) { // EXC_BAD_ACCESS when checking mi.image
        [mi setImage:[mi.image roundedCornerImage:9 borderSize:0]];
    }
}
```

Here is mi at time of crash:

```
mi  HJManagedImageV *   0x0022fae0
    UIView  UIView  
    oid id  0x00000000
    url NSURL * 0x00000000
    moHandler   HJMOHandler *   0x00000000
    image   UIImage *   0x00000000
    imageView   UIImageView *   0x00000000
    callbackOnSetImage  id  0x00000000
    callbackOnCancel    id  0x00000000
    callbackOnError id  0x00000000
    isCancelled BOOL    false
    loadingWheel    UIActivityIndicatorView *   0x00000000
    onImageTap  NSInvocation *  0x00000000
    index   int -1
    modification    int 0
```

I'm puzzled why checking mi.image gives me a crash. How else can I tell if mi is still useable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good design practice that objects that use delegate pattern do not outlive their delegates. However if that is an unnecessary evil, you should make sure that your object's delegate ivar is set to nil when the delegate itself is being deallocated.

In other words,
It's often that delegates happen to be the owners of their objects. Then its the owner's responsibility to clear out the delegate ivars if they expect their children to outlive themselves.